# Outlook Not Receiving Emails Sent From Django Website

Tags: email, outlook, django-email

My Django website has several forms which users fill out and when they submit them an e-mail is sent to my email address. This works when I use my Hotmail address as the receiving address, but not when I use my Outlook email address (the address I'd like to use). I also tried another Outlook address and it worked. So it's just my Outlook that's not receiving them. The Outlook address is also the sending address.

I have no idea why my Outlook address won't receive e-mails from my website, yet it receives e-mails sent from other sources. It displays no error messages so I really have nothing to go off. I have Googled a lot but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

I know my question is vague, but I'm hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction or give me something to look into, because there are no error messages or anything for me to go off. I have also been through the settings in Outlook and can't find anything that would be blocking it.

PS I didn't include any code as I really don't know how it would help, though I can if you think it would be useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked your SPAM/JUNK folder. This might be possible that emails are getting delivered to your SPAM folder instead of INBOX.
2. Check your Firewall Settings might be your Firewall is creating the problem.
3. Check out some possible fixes mentioned here: https://www.tipsoverflow.com/why-outlook-not-receiving-mails-but-can-send-fixed/